# API Account ID in code rather than retrieving through API?

Tags: docusignapi

In the majority of code examples, there will be a call to the `AuthenticationApi` to retrieve the `accountId` from DocuSign. A simple example would be:

```
var configuration = new Configuration(new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restApi"));
SetAuthenticationHeader(configuration);

AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi(configuration);
LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();

// find the default account for this user
foreach (LoginAccount loginAccount in loginInfo.LoginAccounts)
{
    if (loginAccount.IsDefault == "true")
    {
        return loginAccount.AccountId;
    }
}
```

What would be the disadvantage of skipping this step and instead just referencing the `API Account ID` from the DocuSign Admin page and using that value during all of the API calls? This would eliminate the need to login, which seems to only provide the benefit of returning the `accountId` (at least in my case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Amit's answer. In addition:

Don't assume that users will only have one account. As DocuSign installations within organizations grow, it is common to create multiple accounts since some settings are account-specific.

The best UX is to ask the person what account should be used, then cache that information as an application setting. Also enable users to update the setting.

You can also cache the base URL information: while it can change, it is rare for it to do so.

Answer (score 2):

It is not mandatory to use `accountId` from `loginAccount`, but `loginAccount` should be used to read the `baseUrl`. In PROD, your account can be in any datacenter sites `NA1/NA2/NA3 or EU` as of now, in future DocuSign may move your account to another datacenter. So you should read the baseUrl from the API call, and use this baseUrl for further API calls. This could be easily possible using DS OAUTH instead of Legacy Auth Header.

And if your Authentication flow is not using DS OAUTH then you should start using DS OAUTH (which is now recommended by DS as well, check [DS Auth Overview](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html)), which will help you in knowing your datacenter using single host i.e account.docusign.com (for PROD) or account-d.docusign.com (for Demo). You do not need to hard code anything in your application, everything will be driven from DS APIs.